# Where and how can I run my script so that it works autonomously? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, web-services

I have a script in which functions are called one after another and all this happens endlessly through the set interval.I want to run this script somewhere on the server / service (ex: zeit.co) so that it works autonomously. Tell me how to do it better?

ex.script:

```
function one(){
//making post request
}
function two(){
//making get request
}
...
...
function five(){
...
}
setInterval(one,120000)
```

Comment: can you be more specific. What do you mean by a service? what do you mean by being called endlessly. Forexample the functions are called in order like one() two() five() one time or multiple times one() two() five() one() two() five()

Comment: For a service i mean (ex: zeit.co) , I have four functions that are executed in turn and through the setinterval() it all repeats